# can't ssh using l2tp-ipsec-vpn on 13.10

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, ipsec

I am connecting to my office using *l2tp-ipsec-vpn* v 1.0.9 on Ubuntu 13.10. The connection succeeds, and i can ping to internal servers at the office, however when i attemp to ssh to these servers the connection times out stating

```
Connection closed by 10.69.*.***
```

This connection works fine from the same machine booted into OSX.

What should I do ?

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with the MTU settings. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://launchpad.net/~seriy-pr/+archive/network-manager-l2tp

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:seriy-pr/network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
sudo service xl2tpd stop
sudo update-rc.d xl2tpd disable
```